# Getting unique items from comma separated lists in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have the following setup (which is shared by a number of users through office 365 and changed frequently):

[image: Setup image]

I need to collect all unique items from a number of comma-separated lists in a range and write out unique values in rows.

Based on the example above, I need something like this:

[image: Result image]

I have managed to find a solution (I think it was in this forum, or a blog)

```
=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B2:D4),",","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y"))),",","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y")
```

but unfortunately, this solution only works on desktop Excel and does not work with Excel 365 (online Excel). Is there anything I can do in Excel 365 to have the same result?

Comment: I see you are using `TEXTJOIN`, you may need to rewrite but `TEXTSPLIT` should let you get it into the column format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ",,B2:D4),,",")))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. And much better solution compared to XML filtering. Many thanks